# HttpClient send request throws Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F8F

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, activesync

I'm trying to send a web request to an ActiveSync server using HttpClient in Windows Universal App (Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1). When i call the method `SendRequestAsync` it throws Exception

> "HResult:0x80072F8F"

and the response is null.

I found that in the RequestMessage the `HttpRequestMessage.TransportInformation` property contains some information.
`HttpRequestMessage.TransportInformation.ServerCertificate` contains a value and `HttpRequestMessage.TransportInformation.ServerCertificateErrors` contains an Entry with `ChainValidationResult.Untrusted`.

The situation I am trying to solve is: I do not have any certificates. I call an unknown server with HttpClient and that server responds "`ChainValidationResult.Untrusted`".
How can i use the `HttpRequestMessage.TransportInformation.ServerCertificate` in order to make the call successful?

Comment: Is the date/time on your device is correct?

Comment: Yes, the date/time is correct. I think the problem is with certificate and I need a way to use the HttpRequestMessage.TransportInformation.ServerCertificate.

Comment: Another problem that could be is that your device doesn't trust the sever certificate.

Comment: I had this error code when VS was not connecting to the internet via the proxy. The networking guys fixed this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we don't use proxy.